# Cannot install GNU Fortran compiler due to unresolved dependencies

Tags: apt, fortran

I have a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install.  I have updated it without any problem, but when I tried to install the Fortran GNU compiler from Software Center I get the error
`Package dependencies cannot be resolved`.  What is the problem?  I am working behind a proxy.

Comment: can you post the output of apt-get?

Comment: Specifically, the output of running these commands in the Terminal: `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install gfortran`

Answer (score 1):

In Software Centre, type '**gfortran**' into search box.

This will find: **GNU Fortran 95 compiler**

I already have this installed, on **Ubuntu 12.04**.

Comment: Do you still have an issue?  Or is this resolved?